Area3D выдаёт только StaticBody3D у импортированных моделей в Godot
Я пытаюсь сделать звук шагов по разным поверхностям в Godot. Привязал Area3D и коллайдер к игроку и в самом скрипте движения игрока через узел _on_area_3d_body_entered проверяю, на какой поверхности стоит игрок (к какой группе эта поверхность относится), но Godot не реагирует. Решил проверить какое имя получает Area3D когда сталкивается с поверхностью с помощью print(body) и он выдаёт только StaticBody3D, а не само название объекта как в узлах, вероятнее всего из-за этого не определяются и группы, следовательно скрипт не работает. Модель для поверхности, по которой ходит игрок, я импортировал из Blender в формате gltf, может и из-за этого программа не определяет точное название. Можно ли как-то это решить? Далее приведена функция(узел от Area3D в скрипте игрока, проверяющая поверхности):
func _on_area_3d_body_entered(body):
print(body.name)
if body.is_in_group("Forest"):
    print(body)
    forest_sound.volume_db = 0
    floor_sound.volume_db = -80
elif body.is_in_group("Floor"):
    forest_sound.volume_db = -80
    floor_sound.volume_db = 0

Вот что выдаёт терминал по проверке print(body) (MyPlayer-сам игрок определяется корректно видимо потому, что он импортирован через сам Godot):

